# PHP Slim API 404 not found

Tags: php, .htaccess, slim

I'm trying to create an API using php and php slim.

my folder structure:

API:

- app -> app.js
- libs -> Slim
- v1 -> .htaccess and index.php

**htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [QSA,L]
```

**index.php**

```
require '.././libs/Slim/Slim.php';
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();

$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();

$app->get('/orderoverview/:customerID', function ($customerID) {
        echo "Hello " . $customerID;

});
$app->run();
```

This should be easy but every time I go to http://localhost/api/v1/orderoverview/2 I get a 404 Page Not Found.

BUT when I go to http://localhost/api/v1/index.php/orderoverview/2 I do get the result I want to become!

Any remarks or solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a RewriteBase to your htaccess. I noticed you don't have grouping, so I assume you are placing this in a subdirectory of /api/v1

```
RewriteBase /localsites/serf/weap/api/v1
```

Comment: When I do this I get a: Server 500 error! The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in a CGI script.

Comment: I believe it's the trailing slash. It's not needed. If it's still 500 then it is something in the code not the htaccess.

Comment: If this still doesn't work also it's possible I don't have all the information of your environment. You need to follow the rewrite base along the path from the Apache root to the subdirectory hosting the application

Comment: I still get the server error.. my full path is: http://localhost/localsites/serf/weap/api/v1/index.php/orderoverview/5

Comment: Updated answer to match full path also I totally realized I had a colon in my answer. Spend to much time writing JSON :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the `.htaccess` file at your root and put below code.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /api/v1/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I get redirected to my xampp page and when I use the index.php in the url I get a 404

Answer (score 0):

I created this one for you,just Change your .httpaccess file to -

```
DirectoryIndex /v1/index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [QSA,L]
```

Here v1 is the subfolder and index.php is where your functions are.
Hope it helps!